# Flutter fixed button position

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing an application on flutter and I'm having a problem with the position of the ElevatedButton. When the Validator returns the error message below the TextFormField, the widget expands downward and the position of the add button changes. I would like to keep the add button pinned to the same position as the beginning of the app

[button in normal position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdKLA.jpg)

[Button out of its original position after returning the validator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk5Yy.jpg)

My code:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Lista de Compras"),
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      centerTitle: true,
    ),
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 10, 5, 10),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Theme(
                      data: ThemeData(
                          primaryColor: Colors.green,
                          hintColor: Colors.green),
                      child: Expanded(
                          child: TextFormField(
                              controller: _controlador,
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value.isEmpty) {
                                  return "Insira um item";
                                }
                                return null;
                              },
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide:
                                          BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                                  labelText: "Novo item",
                                  hintText: "Insira um item",
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                  labelStyle:
                                      TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
                                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () => _controlador.clear(),
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.clear,
                                        color: Colors.grey),
                                  ))))),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 6)),
                  ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.green,
                          shape: CircleBorder(),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12)),
                      child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                          _addCompras();
                        }
                      }),
                ],
              ),
            )),
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected behaviour, when `TextFormField` show an `errorText` this will append a text below the `TextFormField` adding extra height for about 22. Check working example below :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            MeasureSize(
              child: FormWidget(),
              onChange: (size) {
                print(size);
              },
            ),
            MeasureSize(
              child: FormWidget(hideError: false),
              onChange: (size) {
                print(size);
              },
            ),
            FormWidget(
              hideError: false,
              addPaddingToTrailingButton: true,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FormWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool hideError;
  final bool addPaddingToTrailingButton;

  FormWidget({
    this.hideError = true,
    this.addPaddingToTrailingButton = false,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget trailingButton = ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
      ),
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: () {},
    );

    if (addPaddingToTrailingButton) {
      trailingButton = Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 22),
        child: trailingButton,
      );
    }

    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey[300],
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          SizedBox(width: 8),
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                ),
                labelText: "Label text field",
                hintText: "Hint text field",
                errorText: hideError ? null : 'Error text shown',
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 8),
          trailingButton,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

typedef void OnWidgetSizeChange(Size size);

class MeasureSizeRenderObject extends RenderProxyBox {
  Size oldSize;
  final OnWidgetSizeChange onChange;

  MeasureSizeRenderObject(this.onChange);

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    super.performLayout();

    Size newSize = child.size;
    if (oldSize == newSize) return;

    oldSize = newSize;
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      onChange(newSize);
    });
  }
}

class MeasureSize extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  final OnWidgetSizeChange onChange;

  const MeasureSize({
    Key key,
    @required this.onChange,
    @required Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return MeasureSizeRenderObject(onChange);
  }
}
```

[image: Running example]
I have adding a background so it will show the height difference :

1. TextField without errorText shown.
2. TextField with errorText shown.
3. TextField with errorText shown, with additional padding on icon button.

[Check dartpad here](https://dartpad.dev/f83b6ed2b5145b8a008141e6f7ed0bf7)

Answer (score 0):

the answer by Allan above is very great.
But if you are facing issues learning that do it this way:

- Add Elevated button to Column and add SizedBox with height 22 as its children. Here the height is calculated as (Height of TextFormField with error - of TextFormField without error) using flutter inspector.

```
Column(
    children: [
        ElevatedButton(...),
        SizedBox(
            height: 22,
        ),
    ],
),
```

- Now add `helperText: ' ',` in TextFormField InputDecoration:

```
TextFormField(
    validator: (value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
            return "Insira um item";
        }
            return null;
        },
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        helperText: ' ',
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
        labelText: "Novo item",
        hintText: "Insira um item",
        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
    ),
),
```

[Here](https://dartpad.dev/d14a55db33d11c439f4caa2dc6dc6e85?null_safety=false) you can see the dartpad for full code.

This will get you this result:
[image]